# How to run Shell Script using CHMOD in a folder

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to run my shell script that is stored in a shared folder but I keep receiving errors.

here is my code:

```
chmod +x /home/shared/testing/ddl_engine.sh
./ddl_engine.sh
```

But keep receiving the following error when running the second line of code(./ddl_engine.sh):

[image]

Comment: That has nothing to do with chmod. What are the *contents* of the script? Does its shebang line point to an interpreter that actually exists? Note that if it's a DOS-formatted text file, you could have a carriage return on the end of the line that's being looked for as a file name.

Comment: If something were wrong with the chmod, you'd have an error message about permissions, not one about the file not being found.

Comment: ...so, the linked duplicate has *some* answers that are specific to compiled executables, but there are also several applicable to scripts; one of them should quite certainly cover your use case.